# React JS Google Map usage limits

Tags: node.js, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, npm

I have just started using React JS and I am currently working on getting the google maps "google-maps-react" package up and running.

From my basic understanding of React JS, any change causes a whole component hierarchy to re-render.

From my understanding of the Google usage information via this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload); any re-render constitutes as a usage.

**Question**
So with that, how do React JS developers handle\deal with this problem? 25,000 free map renders pre-React is fairly substantial but it seems like a fairly simple cap to burst with frameworks like React that cause a re-render for any change in your hierarchy.

**Option 1**
Is the best way to ensure the map component is not nested in a hierarchy that is updatable by other components? I wrote a sample application and confirmed that only the components in the hierarchy that invoked the change are re-rendered.

If this is the best way, that is fine but I am hoping to hear from more experienced React developers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that the "google-map-react" NPM package is doing something interesting behind the scenes. It is actually sending an update to your markers with the latest map state.

Once I found this, I tied into that behaviour and now my map only renders once and I dynamically handle marker changes based on this behaviour.

I was not able to find this behaviour documented anywhere but happened to stumble upon it via a console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props)) within my marker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 25k limit refers to you requesting the google maps js sdk, not how often you instantiate a `google.maps.Map` object.

And yes, it would be good practice to not re-render the component encapsulating the map all the time.

Check this simple map component:

https://github.com/Scarysize/react-maps-popup/blob/master/src/map.js

It initializes the map once and propagates the map instance up using a function as a child approach (ofc you could simply pass a callback as a prop).

Comment: That is how I implemented it. That being said, it is each load of the map that increments the usage counter as per here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload